# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pipenv

I'm running Python 3.9.1 with pipenv virtual enviroment. I've already installed beautifulsoup with:

```
pipenv install beautifulsoup4
```

It seem to be installed correctly. I do import using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And then run some bs commands. Howeever, when I run the .py file, the following error is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Dev\folder\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Any ideas how to solve this? I've try installing, reinstalling and updating but no solution so foar.

Thanks!

Comment: do pip freeze from the terminal where you are running your code, and check if it has bs4

Comment: Try installing it globally : ```pip install beautifulsoup4 --user```

Comment: @AhmedO `--user` is the opposite of a global install

Comment: oh, my bad ,, just noticed ,, thanks

Comment: Try adding something like: `import bs4, sys; print([requests.__version__, bs4.__version__, sys.version])` to the top of your script and then run it both ways again. Chances are in one case you are not in your virtual environment. Or just print the `sys.version`

Comment: @gsb22 Yes I do: beautifulsoup4==4.9.3

Comment: @MartinEvans I tried that and following error is displayed: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`. I already checked with pip freeze, and it IS installed :(.

Comment: Ok, add `print(sys.prefix, sys.base_prefix)` both manually and also when you run the `.py` script. This will prove that both are running in the same environment.